# Why do `keyup` and `if` not work in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want if values into input was equal with one of the words `ed Or d Or i Or ei` done perform the operation it. i can not change value input `value="ed"` in first run page. what do i do?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZsYdY/3/

```
<input type="text" value="ed">
<div class="code"></div>


function ticket_check() {
    //var val = 'ticket_code=' + $('.ticket_code').val();
    var input_val = $('input').val();
    if (input_val == 'ed Or d Or i Or ei') {
        $('.code').empty().hide().fadeIn('slow').append('It is ok');
    } else {

            $('.code').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).hide().fadeIn('slow').append('It is not ok');
            })

    }
}

$('.input').live('keyup change', function () {
    ticket_check();
    var input_val = $('input').val();
    if (input_val == 'ed Or d Or i Or ei') {
        $('.code').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).hide().fadeIn('slow').append('It is not oooooooookkkkkkkkk');
        })
    }
});
ticket_check()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (input_val == 'ed Or d Or i Or ei') {
```

needs to be:

```
if (input_val == 'ed' || input_val == 'd' || input_val == 'i' || input_val == 'ei') {
```

And `$('.input')` should be `$('input')` in your example

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsYdY/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to check whether the input equals one of the given suggestions:

```
//Case-sensitive
'ed d i ei'.split(' ').indexOf(input_val) != -1

//Alternatively, case-sensitive:
['ed', 'd', 'i', 'ei'].indexOf(input_val) != -1;

//Case-insensitive:
'ed d i ei'.split(' ').indexOf(input_val.toLowerCase()) != -1
```

The concept behind this example is: "Split a string in a list of valid values *and* check whether the current value occurs".
Example:

```
function ticket_check() {
    //var val = 'ticket_code=' + $('.ticket_code').val();
    var valid_values = 'ed d i ei'.split(' ');
    var input_val = $('input').val().toLowerCase();
    if (valid_values.indexOf(input_val) != -1) {
        //Rest of code
```

Comment: Good answer, except I dont think the `Or`s were supposed to be in that string. I think that was the OP attempting some boolean logic.

Comment: @Jamiec I've removed OR. The separator can be basically anything, in case a valid match contains a space.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.... your input doesn't have the class '.input' on it.  So this line should look like this

```
$('input').live('keyup change', function () {
```

Also, as others have stated... your or is messed up.  Look at one of the above answers for that.